How to print contents of input files to kubectl kustomize command
I have a azure devops pipeline to deploy my helm chart to Kubernetes cluster.
In helm upgrade command I have specified --post-renderer which runs a script
This script runs command
kubectl kustomize ./
kustomization.yaml contents
resources:
  - deployment.yml 
patches:
  - target:      
      kind: Deployment      
    path: set_affinitytolerations.yml

While running the pipeline I can see the error
error: accumulating resources: accumulating resources from 'deployment.yml': MalformedYAMLError: yaml: line 3: did not find expected key in File: deployment.yml

Is there any way I can print the input deployment.yaml file being fed to kustomize
I am using
Client Version: v1.32.0
Kustomize Version: v5.5.0
Server Version: v1.26.10+rke2r2

I checked command line options available for for kustomize by running
kubectl kustomize --help

But couldn't find any option

What if instead of using --post-renderer, you run helm template to output the manifests to a local directory, and then manually run kubectl kustomize on the result?

Kustomize itself doesn't have a built-in print input files option.
However, You can try this workaround that might work in your case :

Modify your post-render script. This approach uses cat to print the content of your deployment.yml and set\_affinitytolerations.yml files directly after they've been rendered.

#!/bin/bash

# Print the contents of the deployment.yml before kustomize
echo "Contents of deployment.yml"
cat ./templates/deployment.yml

# Print the contents of affinitytolerations.yml before kustomize
echo "Contents of affinitytolerations.yml"
cat ./templates/set_affinitytolerations.yml

kubectl kustomize ./

Notes : Make sure to edit the correct path in cat where your files are located.

After modifying your post-render script. Run this command directly just to view the output of deployment instead of helm upgrade.

./post-renderer.sh

You might also want to debug the issue you encountered: MalformedYAMLError: yaml: line 3: did not find expected key in File: deployment.yml. It indicates that the deployment.yml file has a syntax error pointing to line 3 of your deployment.yml file. This could be due to missing key, incorrect indentation or formatting issues YAML is very sensitive to formatting and indentation even a small mistake can cause issues.
I suggest looking for Syntax issues such as:

Indentation: ensure you're using two spaces per level (not tabs).

Missing or extra colon, hyphen, or quote.

Data type mismatches


For further information you can check this documentation : https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/
